# Read Lan ,Long from Json URL and assign the lat and long to map 's markers?

Tags: android, json, google-maps

i am new to android ,, i am trying to read json file from URL , and get the lat ,and long , and 
assine  the values to markers and show it in map ,my question how to get lan, long, after reading the content of json ??
here is the json url data
json data on the URL

```
{"properties":{"1":{"name":"Villa For 
Sale","lat":"35.2474962142","lng":"-91.3480163353","price":"$100,000","image1":"http:\/\/wpl28.realtyna.com\/theme28\/wp-content\/uploads\/WPL\/91\/thimg_12_800x420.jpg","image2":"http:\/\/wpl28.realtyna.com\/theme28\/wp-content\/uploads\/WPL\/85\/thimg_2_800x420.jpg"},"2":{"name":"Apartment For Rent","lat":"35.9542249162","lng":"-101.21893164","price":"$40,000","image1":"ht
```

in android i want to get the lat, long and assing each value to a market 
    map

```
      //this method should get json data from onPostExecute(String s)
      public void the_received_data(String received_data){

       }

      class Read_JSON extends AsyncTask<String ,String ,String >{
       MainActivity mainActivity;
       // class to handle reading json file
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection connection =null;
        BufferedReader data =null;
        InputStream json_data;
        try {
           URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection =(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            //holding the data into stream
            json_data =connection.getInputStream();
            data = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(json_data));
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            //read the data from the bufferedredaer line by line
            String line ="";
            while((line =data.readLine()) != null){
                stringBuffer.append(line);
            }
            return stringBuffer.toString();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            if(connection !=null){connection.disconnect();}
            try {
                if(data != null){
                    data.close();}
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
      return null; }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
         super.onPostExecute(s);
         mainActivity.the_received_data(s);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

After getting string response, just parse that to JSONObject like below sample example & then you can get Latitude & Longitude.

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject("{"name":"myName","address":"myAddress"}");
String my_name = jsonObj.getString("myName");
```